# How to transform the size of the image dynamically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview

I want to crop the selected portion of the image that user has selected. I would like to implement like in the following image
[image]

[image]

By moving the button/image(green bordered box) , the user can select the portion he wants. Can any one please tell me how to do this or please provide me the sample code if you have any.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [BJImageCropper](https://github.com/barrettj/BJImageCropper). This also have an example.

Comment: Thanks, Nice project, Can you tell me any project that has an option to crop the selected area.